# How to set varying alpha parameter in python alphashape

Tags: python, lambda, alpha-shape

#### Environment

- [Alpha Shape Toolbox](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#using-a-varying-alpha-parameter) version: 1.3.1
- Python version: 3.9.12
- Operating System: windows 10 19044.1826

#### Questions

I tried to understand how to set a varying Alpha parameter from [this tutorial](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#using-a-varying-alpha-parameter) but with no vail.

Here's the code

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
import alphashape

points_2d = [(0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.),(0.5, 0.25), (0.5, 0.75), (0.25, 0.5), (0.75, 0.5)]

alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(
    points_2d,
    lambda ind, r: 1.0 + any(np.array(points_2d)[ind][:,0] == 0.0))
alpha_shape
```

My questions lie in this line of code:

```
lambda ind, r: 1.0 + any(np.array(points_2d)[ind][:,0] == 0.0)
```

- Is `ind` the iterator that loops through the points array?
- From the [source file](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/alphashape/alphashape.html#alphashape), it seems that `r` is circumradius of the simplex. How is this value obtained and used?
- What does `[:,0]` mean?

Also, more examples on setting varying alpha parameter would be highly appreciated, e.g. based on point density, or by passing in an alpha parameter list.